# WordPress Shortcode generated Shortcode is not applied (Pods, Leaflet)

Tags: php, wordpress, leaflet, shortcode

I want to output a list of locations as a table and mark them up on a map. For this I have created a content type in WordPress with Pods with a property "Address". With a Pods shortcode, I am able to have the table created and list all the entries. With another Pods shortcode, I am able to generate a Leaflet shortcode.

The problem is that the Leaflet shortcode is output to the frontend, but is not interpreted by Leaflet as a map. If I use the Leaflet shortcode generated by Pods from the frontend in the backend, the map works as desired.

I'm afraid the problem arises because the shortcode generated by a shortcode is not taken into account and implemented.

I have created a WordPress page and noted the following shortcode:

`[pods name="locations"]<br /><br />[/pods][pods name="locations"]<br />[leaflet-marker address="{@locations-address}"]<br />[/pods]`

A correct shortcode is output in the frontend:

`[leaflet-marker address="Ingolstädter Str. 101, 80939 München"]`

In consultation with the developer of the Leaflet plugin for WordPress, I tried to insert the function with XYZ PHP code:

```
<?php
$a = do_shortcode( '[pods name="locations"][leaflet-marker]' . '[' . 'leaflet-marker address={@locations-address}' . '&#093' . '<br>[/pods]');
echo "[leaflet-map]  $a [leaflet-marker]";
?>
```

The result is better, as the map is generated largely as desired, but when I insert the XYZ PHP code into the WordPress page, no map is output.

Comment: _"The result is better, as the map is generated largely as desired, but when I insert the XYZ PHP code into the WordPress page, no map is output."_ - can't make sense of this. You say, when you used XYZ PHP code to insert this, the map was _"generated largely as desired"_, but then you say when you _"insert the XYZ PHP code into the WordPress page, no map is output"_ ...? What is supposed to be the difference between the two? It sounds as if you are saying you did the same thing, but with different results.

Comment: I am guessing that perhaps the result of `echo "[leaflet-map]  $a [leaflet-marker]"` is output into a context, where WP doesn't automatically parse for shortcodes again? Maybe you just need another "level" of `do_shortcode()` at this point then? `echo do_shortcode("[leaflet-map]  $a [leaflet-marker]");` Or all in one go, `echo do_shortcode("[leaflet-map][pods name="locations"][leaflet-marker][leaflet-marker address={@locations-address}&#093<br>[/pods][leaflet-marker]");`

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your answer! The double use of do_shortcode() was an important part to the solution! Regarding XYZ PHP code, there is the possibility to preview the result and insert it as shortcode. The former worked, the latter did not. I will use my own plug-in instead of XYZ PHP in the future.

Answer (score 0):

By default including a shortcode within a Pods shortcode will not work. If you need this functionality to work, you need to include the following constant in your wp_config.php file:

```
define('PODS_SHORTCODE_ALLOW_SUB_SHORTCODES',true);
```

Then, if you need to parse a shortcode within the Pods template, custom template or within your Pods shortcode, just add  `shortcodes=1`  to the Pods shortcode.

Or you can use the filter below to have it always enabled:

```
add_filter( 'pods_shortcode', function( $tags )  {
  $tags[ 'shortcodes' ] = true;
  return $tags;
});
```

All these are explained [at Pod's documentation](https://docs.pods.io/displaying-pods/pods-templates/using-shortcodes-in-pods-templates/).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution in the meantime. The keyword is nested shortcodes (https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) and the function "do_shortcode()".

Using a custom WordPress plug-in to run a script and output it as a custom shortcode, I was able to generate the map as desired. For this I used the following code. It is important to note that "do_shortcode()" must be used twice, first for Pods and then for Leaflet.

```
function map_func( $atts ){
    
        $leaflet_map_shortcode = "[leaflet-map lat=48.13391418715657 lng=11.582841421510087 zoom=15 fitbounds max_zoom=19]";
        $leaflet_map = do_shortcode($leaflet_map_shortcode);
    
        $placese_marks_shortcode = '[pods name="places"]<br />[leaflet-marker address="{@places-address}" [...] [/leaflet-marker]<br />[/pods]';
        $placese_marks = do_shortcode($placese_marks_shortcode);
        $placese_marks2 = do_shortcode($placese_marks);
        return $leaflet_map . $placese_marks2;
        
    }
    add_shortcode( 'map2', 'map_func' );
```